# Run Ionic Android App natively on device with out being plugged in

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I am new to ionic and am trying to run my application on my android device without needing it to be plugged in.  I have the app running, and if my device is plugged in, it runs perfectly, but once I unplug it, it says `Err_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

I realize it is somehow pulling from the webserver that ionic spins up, and once I remove the connection it no longer has access, but how do I get it to run without being connected?  Do I need to deploy the website to a server and somohow point the android app to it?

Any help would be highly appreciated, I cannot find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the apk and install it on your Android device.

1) Go to Build>Build apk(s)
2) After it is done a popup will be shown by the Android Studio. Click on locate and you will find your .apk file as 'android-debug.apk'.

You can then make a link by uploading it on diawi.com or any other app sharing tool, and install it on your phone using that link.
That way it won't need to be plugged in to your system.